# Creating modifications to a scatterplot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, roc

I have the following dataset

```
CombinedScores<-c("zero", "5", "10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40", 
                                    "45", "50", "60", "G", "LG", "GF",
"FER", 
                                  "VAR", "LOPE", "DAR", "CCOR", 
                                    "LTR", "Ideal")
FalsePositiveRate<-c(0, 0.04, 0.07, 0.1, 0.18, 0.26, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.71, 0.8, 0.96, 0.1, 0.26, 
                    0.07, 0.49, 0.07, 0.26, 0.05, 0.28, 0.03, 1 )
TruePositiveRate<-c(0, 0.4, 0.4, 0.53, 0.8, 0.8, 0.92, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                    0.53, 0.8, 0.47, 0.93, 0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
MetricOrAlternate<-c("Metric", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", 
                  "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Metric", "Metric", "Metric", "Metric", 
                  "Metric", "Metric", "Metric", "Metric", 
                  "Metric", "Metric")

COMBINEDTABLE<-data.frame(CombinedScores, FalsePositiveRate, TruePositiveRate, MetricOrAlternate)
```

I am trying to create a graph with FalsePositiveRate as the x axis and the TruePositiveRate as the y axis with range of 0 to 1 on both x axis and y axis. I also want to color code if its a "Metric" or "Alternate" with a clear nice legend. Similarly I want to draw a yellow line connecting the following points(0,0.5) and (0.5, 1) and label only those scores that are in the top left corner that are above this line.

I have created the following code:

```
ggplot(COMBINEDTABLE, aes(FalsePositiveRate, TruePositiveRate)) + 
  geom_point() + coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0, 1))+
  geom_text_repel(label=CombinedScores, nudge_y = 0.02, nudge_x = 0.02, min.segment.length = 5)
```

but for some reason, I cannot add the color code labels to label each point if it is a Metric or Alternate and cannot add the line connecting (0,0.5) and (0.5, 1) and similarly so it only has a specific score label for those that fall above the line.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a color according to Metric means adding this in the `aes` part of the call to ggplot. Adding a straight line is a call to `geom_abline` and to check whether a point is above or below the line we can use an `ifelse` statement. I also took the freedom to add a `coord_fixed` for this graph.

```
combined <- structure(list(CombinedScores = c("zero", "5", "10", "15", "20", 
                       "25", "30", "35", "40", "45", "50", "60", "G", "LG", "GF", "FER", 
                       "VAR", "LOPE", "DAR", "CCOR", "LTR", "Ideal"), FalsePositiveRate = c(0, 
                       0.04, 0.07, 0.1, 0.18, 0.26, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.71, 0.8, 0.96, 
                       0.1, 0.26, 0.07, 0.49, 0.07, 0.26, 0.05, 0.28, 0.03, 1), TruePositiveRate = c(0, 
                       0.4, 0.4, 0.53, 0.8, 0.8, 0.92, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.53, 0.8, 0.47, 
                       0.93, 0.4, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 0.8, 1), MetricOrAlternate = c("Metric", 
                       "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", 
                       "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", "Alternate", 
                       "Alternate", "Metric", "Metric", "Metric", "Metric", "Metric", 
                       "Metric", "Metric", "Metric", "Metric", "Metric")), 
                       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

ggplot(combined, aes(x = FalsePositiveRate, y = TruePositiveRate, color = MetricOrAlternate)) + 
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = .5, lwd = 2.5, color = "grey") +
  geom_point(size =4, alpha = .8) + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0, 1)) +
  coord_fixed() +
  geom_text_repel(label = ifelse(TruePositiveRate > .5 + FalsePositiveRate,
                                 yes = CombinedScores, no = ""), 
                  box.padding = 0.5)
```

[image]

If you plan to do more work like this, consider looking at the pROC package.